# SQL Group by with aggregation and Distinct

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

Given :

InsuranceCompanies  (**cid**, name, phone, address)

Doctors (**did**, name, specialty, address, phone, age, cid)

Patients (**pid**, name, address, phone, age, gender, cid)

Visits     (**vid**, did, pid, date, description)

where

```
cid - Insurance Company code
did - doctor code
pid - patient code
vid - code of visit
```

and a TASK :    For each doctor return the number of (different) patients of age 20-25:

is :

```
SELECT  V.did, COUNT ( V.pid ) 
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT V1.did, V1.pid
            FROM    Visits V1,Patient P
            WHERE   P.pid=V1.pid and P.age >= 20 and  P.age <=25 ) AS V 
GROUP BY    V.did
```

equivalent to :

```
SELECT  V.did, COUNT (DISTINCT V.pid ) 
FROM    Visits V,Patient P
WHERE   P.pid=V.pid and P.age >= 20 and  P.age <=25
GROUP BY    V.did
```

and are they both a good solution to the task?

Comment: Should `V1.pid` be `V1.id` in the first example?

Comment: Avoid subqueries where you can - to that end your second approach is better (and faster, especially with large data sets)

Comment: The second one is better because it simpler, making it more readable and possibly easier for the query optimizer to select the best plan.

Comment: @Madbreaks - Not true for this query. That admonition really only applies to correlated subqueries, which this is not. That said, the first query is more complicated than it needs to be, which is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example looks fine to me.  When this is compiled into a plan, the RDBMS will work out how best to approach it from a number of algorithms.  I don't see the need to add the middle step you introduce in the first version.

If you are extremely keen to be sure you have the best approach, look at the plans generated and compare them.  And look at reads, CPU time, etc.

How to do that depends on the particular RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Your second query is more appropriate to the task, and should optimize better.  Also, in each query, you reference Visit.age.  Shouldn't you join to pateints and reference patient.age?

Also, in each you are counting unique visits the doctor has, which does not require the distinct statement since visits are never duplicated.  Instead, you should be counting distinct patients (p.id).

Comment: right. i missed it because it was less relevent to the point i tried to talk about...

Comment: The second query does not handle distinct patients, just distinct visits

Comment: spinning_plate: you are correct, it should be COUNT(DISTINCT P.id).  I will update my response to reflect this.

Comment: The key on Vist lets you have more than a 1 visit of a patient to a doctor, therefore the DISTINCT

Comment: Ofek: I understand the purpose of the visit table, but in your question you stated that you wanted to know the number of patients per doctor, which is not what your queries do.  Instead they find the number of visits per doctor, which doesn't require the distinct keyword.  If you would like to know the number of visits per doctor, try `SELECT did, count(*) from visits group by did`.

Comment: notice the  (different) patients notation, that means, according to my understanding (correct me if otherwise) that we are not intrested in counting twice a visit to a specific doctor by a specific patient twice... therefore the DISTINCT

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT V.id)` counts every visit once, and thus the DISTINCT keyword is unnecessary as ever visit is listed only once.  `COUNT(DISTINCT V.pid)` counts every patient once, and the DISTINCT is necessary, as each patient is listed once per visit.

Comment: you mean COUNT(DISTINCT V.vid) is, yeah it was not clear at first because i misstyped the p...

Answer (score 0):

The first query works, but is not really common practice.

The second query is the way to go, much clearer what happens as well.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different queries, possibly

1) You are counting distinct visits between a patient and a doctor, this means that if a patient sees a doctor twice, you won't count it

2) You are just counting visits by doctor, if there are multiple visits by the same patient, they will get counted twice

So for the task, 1) is the correct answer but 2) looks better

```
SELECT  V.did, COUNT ( V.id ) 
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT V1.did, V1.pid
            FROM    Visits V1
            WHERE V1.age >= 20 and  V1.age <=25 ) AS V  
GROUP BY    V.did
```

could be better written as

```
SELECT  V.did, COUNT ( V.pid ) ### change here
FROM    Visits, ### your joins
            WHERE V1.age >= 20 and  V1.age <=25 
GROUP BY    V.did
```

Comment: 1 - I dont want to count it, i need to know how many diffrent patients a doctor had a visit from, therefore im not counting a visit by the same patient to the same doctor twice...

Comment: I'm speaking of your queries - the answer to  your problem is (your) query 1), which you've written. A way to pretty it up is to make it in the query I have suggested

Comment: In other words, your query (2) does NOT accomplish your goal, but modifying it just a small way will

Comment: Write your modification as you think is right... and we'll judge

Comment: Huh? this is hte second query in my answer, looks like you've alreayd changed it in yours.  Your original query was calling DISTINCT on the V.id NOT the patient

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a left join, because it says `for each doctor` and you're not displaying doctors with no visits with a `0`:

```
select d.did, count(distinct p.pid) from doctor d
left join visits v on d.did = v.did
join patients p on v.pid = p.pid
where p.age between 20 and 25
group by d.did
```